# Retriving Array values from the NSMutableArray in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am working with an application in which i am getting photoID ,which is a string.
I am storing that photoID in array,and again add that array in another array.
Below iS the code::

```
 NSString *photoID;
    arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:photoID];
    [arr arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:array];
         //number=(int)arr[1];
          NSLog(@"arr :  %@",arr);
           NSLog(@"arr[0] :  %@",arr[0]);
         NSLog(@"arr[1] :  %@",arr[1]);
          NSLog(@"Number1 :  %@",number1);
            NSLog(@"Number :  %d",number);
```

when i tried to access the value of arr[1],my application crashes.
i don't know what am i doing wrong.am i doing wrong to add strings in array,and truing to access unsaved data?
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed so the first object in an array is it index 0. When you access the object at index 1 you are trying to access the second object. As you haven't added a second object to your array there is an exception / crash

Comment: You seem to be having difficulty with very, very basic programming. I recommend you follow a tutorial on iOS programming before continuing. Look at "Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad" on iTunesU or http://raywenderlich.com

Comment: thankyou for your kind suggestion,but your answer should be appreciated

Comment: I suspect you are way over your head.  Objective-C is not an easy language to learn, and you are well-advised to first learn program basics using C or Java.

Answer (score 0):

It is because this line: `[arr arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:array];` does nothing to the `arr`, it only

> Returns a new array that is a copy of the receiving array with the
>   objects contained in another array added to the end.

You should replace it with `[arr addObjectsFromArray:array];`. And also, you only have 1 element in `arr` which is at index 0, so the `arr[1]` should crash but `arr[0]` should work.

Comment: thanks for replying,,but sir i am adding three values in array,but not getting in the values at a time after the scope,,how can i do it

Comment: but when i add 3 different values and try to retrieve that,i am not getting the right value.How can i do that??how can i add values of strings in arr or array??

Comment: Also, `initWithCapacity` is only a hint, there is nothing in the array until you actually add items to it.

Comment: You were adding a single object at this line: `[array addObject:photoID];`

Answer (score 0):

First array should be NSArray if you want to arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray or addObjectsFromArray

```
NSArray *array1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
    NSMutableArray *array2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array2 addObjectsFromArray:array1];
    NSLog(@"%d",array2.count);
```

You can also use like this:

```
NSMutableArray *innerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
    NSMutableArray *outerArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(int i=0;i<=innerArray.count;i++)
    {
        [outerArray addObject:innerArray];

    }
```

Comment: @singh,, can you please tell me that when i am getting values as string i want toad that in array,, so how can i add in the array1,bcoz addobject method is not present for NSArray,Please help me out

Comment: You can use both array as an NSMutableArray and add object in first array using addobject method  then depending on count of first array you can add first array as an object to the second array.